Track Google Analytics for AMP pages when user clicks on anchor text
<div class="base2"><a href="tel:+917411951943" id="Call">CALL NOW</a></div><span>|</span>

For the above code in my AMP page I want to make sure when the person clicks on the anchor tag it is recorded in google-analytics
<!-- Load AMP -->
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>

    <!-- Load amp-analytics -->
    <script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Configure analytics to use gtag -->
    <amp-analytics type="gtag" data-credentials="include">
      <script type="application/json">
        {
          "vars": {
            "gtag_id": "<GA_MEASUREMENT_ID>",
            "config": {
              "<GA_MEASUREMENT_ID>": { "groups": "default" }
            }
          },
          "triggers": {
            "button": {
              "selector": "#the-button",
              "on": "click",
              "vars": {
                "event_name": "login",
                "method": "Google"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      </script>
    </amp-analytics>

What changes should I make in the above code for it to work?
